# Providing JSON type for field in DTO for Json? type in prisma model throws error

Tags: mysql, json, nestjs, prisma

[image]

create-dealer-dto.ts file

```
export class CreateDealerDto {
  @IsOptional()
  ccm: JSON;
}
```

schema.prisma file

```
model Dealer {
  id                Int          @id @default(autoincrement())
  
  ccm               Json?
  createdBy         Int          @map("created_by")
  createdAt         DateTime     @default(now()) @map("created_at")
  updatedAt         DateTime     @updatedAt @map("updated_at")
  deletedBy         Int?         @map("deleted_by")
  deletedAt         DateTime?    @map("deleted_at")
 
  @@map("dealers")
}
```

dealer-service.ts file

```
async create(createDealerDto: CreateDealerDto): Promise<Dealer> {
      this.prismaService.dealer.create({ data: createDealerDto });
    return this.prismaService.dealer.create({
      data: createDealerDto,
    });
  }
```

What shall be the problem? If i try using string in dto error is gone but it is not saved as JSON object it is saved as string.

Comment: Can you share the data object which you are trying to insert? I would like to reproduce this locally and check.

Comment: @NurulSundarani, data object am inserting is [{url:"someurl", name:"something"}]

Comment: I tried storing an array as a JSON field in MySQL and it was stored as a JSON instead of string. Can you provide a minimal reproduction so that I can investigate?